# XStream not ignoring Unknown Elements when using JavaBeanConverter

Tags: java, xstream

I am using XStream 1.4.7 to handle de/serialisation of POJOs. As the project develops, I will need to add new features and therefore new class fields. I would like old versions of the app to handle these changes gracefully and to ignore unknown tags.

```
xs = new XStream();
xs.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
xs.ignoreUnknownElements();
xs.registerConverter(new JavaBeanConverter(xs.getMapper(),
    new TransientRespectingBeanProvider()), XStream.PRIORITY_VERY_LOW);
```

Yesterday I added a String field to one of my classes and serialised it. An older version of the app was not able to deserialise the xml.

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No field 'materialNrVersion' found in class 'com.company.ProjectConfiguration' : No field 'materialNrVersion' found in class 'com.company.ProjectConfiguration'
---- Debugging information ----
message             : No field 'materialNrVersion' found in class 'com.company.ProjectConfiguration'
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.MissingFieldException
cause-message       : No field 'materialNrVersion' found in class 'com.company.ProjectConfiguration'
class               : com.company.ProjectConfiguration
required-type       : com.company.ProjectConfiguration
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.javabean.JavaBeanConverter
line number         : 192
version             : 1.4.7
```

Should I be doing this a different way?

**UPDATE**
If I comment out the `registerConverter` call, then the unknown fields are ignored. The `JavaBeanConverter` seems to be affecting the way the `ignoreUnknownElements` is handled. The `TransientRespectingBeanProvider` is intended to ignore properties which have a `@Transient`annotation.

Can anyone suggest a solution or workaround? An alternative approach to the `@Transient` issue?

Answer (score 0):

The xStream source code is quite clear and straightforward. You can subclass the JavaBeanConverter and tweak its *unmarshal* method, and register the tweaked converter for some or all of your classes. In particular, if you look into the JavaBeanConverter.unmarhal() source, there is

```
if (propertyExistsInClass) {
    ...
} else {
    throw new MissingFieldException(resultType.getName(), propertyName);
}
```

So, if you override the class, copy the original unmarshal method code, and only comment out the *throw ...* line, it should work fine for you. I have used such hacks for XStream a couple of times and it always worked as I would have expected, no nasty surprises.